# TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable _

Tags: sqlite, python-3.7

I attempting to use python to find out how may babies were born in a certain year but am receiving the following error TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Attached below is my python code

```
 c.execute(query)
res = c.fetchone()[0]
num_boys = str(res["TotalBoys"])
num_girls = str(res["TotalGirls"])
num_babies = num_boys + num_girls
```

Answer (score 0):

try :-

```
res = c.cursor
c.execute(query)
row = c.fetchone()
num_boys = row[0]
num_girls = row[1]
num_babies = num_boys + num_girls
```

Comment: Just did- question - should the response be INT? I believed I was using some string functions on values that are INT. My challenge was trying to reassign the INT values as string when I go to print. then do my math. then convert int to str and print.

Comment: @MarkAmon oops changed answer.

Comment: c.execute(query)
    res = c.fetchall()
    tup = res[0]
    num_boys = tup[0]
    num_girls = tup[1]
    num_babies = num_boys + num_girls